# Scala how to create implicit object with same name as function

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, implicit, companion-object

Given the following trait and companion object definitions:

```
trait Api {
  def foo(s: String): String
}

object Api extends Api {
  override def foo(s: String) = s
}
```

I would like to extend the companion object's foo method to have a property function and for that, I use the following implicit class:

```
implicit class ExtendApi(api: Api.type) {
  object foo {
    def asInt(s: String): Int = s.toInt
  }
}

println (Api.foo.asInt("1")) // Does not work
```

However, using this does compile. I get an error:

```
missing argument list for method foo in object Api
Unapplied methods are only converted to functions when a function type is expected.
You can make this conversion explicit by writing `foo _` or `foo(_)` instead of `foo`.
```

It seems scala is not resolving the implicit definition to find the `foo` object.

I tried to be explicit by writing:

```
println (implicitly[Api.type].foo.asInt("1"))
```

Now I get another error:

```
could not find implicit value for parameter e: Playground.this.Api.type
```

This new error does not make sense to me.

Is what I am trying to do possible? How can I fix the errors? Thank you.

[Scastie Link](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/IyocFKNyQfOzpbsie1c0RA)

Comment: The Scala compiler will never chose an extension method over a normal one. Also, I am not sure you can use an inner object as an extension method. Why do you need this?

Comment: It will prefer the extension with a different signature; inner object with apply is OK for extension (because it's just looking for a member), but with the same name, spec 7.3 says only methods are eligible.

Comment: You inspired a bug report: https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/11866

Comment: @som-snytt Oh dam, that's an interesting bug report